# Using ltrim and rtrim in combination of substring

Tags: function, arguments, substring

Hey there so I'm in the process of another project conversion there is a line written in Oracle SQL and I'm trying to convert it to MS SQL:

Oracle PL/SQL:

```
IF LTRIM(sCmtStr) IS NOT NULL THEN
        sTrimStr := ' '||SUBSTR(RTRIM(LTRIM(sCmtStr),'; '),1,999);
    ELSE
        sTrimStr := NULL;
```

MS T-SQL:

```
IF ltrim(@sCmtStr) IS NOT NULL

     SET @sTrimStr = ' ' + ISNULL(substring(rtrim(ltrim(@sCmtStr), '; '), 1, 999), '')
  ELSE 
     SET @sTrimStr = NULL
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TRIMCOMMENT, Line 12
The rtrim function requires 1 argument(s).
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: The error is fairly clear. rtrim takes 1 argument. You've given it two.

Answer (score 0):

RTRIM (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql) Does not take 2 arguments; it can only trim spaces from the end of a string.

TRIM (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql), on the other hand, can be given other characters to remove. It will remove the characters from both ends, however, so you might have to fiddle a bit if you only want it to remove from the end of the string.